# A more faster (optimized) solution to image decimation (C++)

Tags: c, algorithm, image-processing, optimization, image-optimization

I am looking for a more faster way of dealing with the following C code. I have an image of 640x480 and I want to decimate it by a factor of 2 by removing every other rows and columns in the image. I have attached the code in the following. Is there any better way to optimize the code.

```
#define INPUT_NUM_ROW 480
#define INPUT_NUM_COL 640
#define OUTPUT_NUM_ROW 240
#define OUTPUT_NUM_COL 320

unsigned char inputBuf[INPUT_NUM_ROW* INPUT_NUM_COL];
unsigned char outputBuf[OUTPUT_NUM_ROW* OUTPUT_NUM_COL];

void imageDecimate(unsigned char *outputImage , unsigned char *inputImage)
{
/* Fill in your code here */
for (int p = 0; p< OUTPUT_NUM_ROW; p++) {
    for (int q = 0; q < OUTPUT_NUM_COL; q++) {
        outputImage[p*OUTPUT_NUM_COL + q] = inputImage[(p*INPUT_NUM_COL+q)*2];
        // cout << "The pixel at " << p*OUTPUT_NUM_COL+q << " is " << outputImage[p*OUTPUT_NUM_COL+q] << endl;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: most images have a lot of header fields that will need to be updated.  The posted code is only processing the actual data/pixel fields.   Most pixel fields are (depending on the header info) either 3 or 4 bytes long.  when compressing a image, do not arbitrarily eliminate 1/2 the rows and 1/2 the columns.   A much better approach is to average pairs of rows,  Then (in a separate loop) average pairs of columns, remembering that each column (a pixel) consists of 3 or 4 bytes.   Also remember that (in most images) the number of bytes in a row will be a multiple of 4,

Comment: You are right on the header fields inclusion in the images as well as averaging pixels which in turn makes aliasing less prominent. However, I was looking for a more code optimization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than doing the math every time in the inner loop, you could do this:

```
int outputIndex;
int inputIndex;
for (int p = 0; p< OUTPUT_NUM_ROW; p++) {
    inputIndex = p * INPUT_NUM_COL * 2;
    outputIndex = p * OUTPUT_NUM_COL;
    for (int q = 0; q < OUTPUT_NUM_COL; q++) {
        outputImage[outputIndex] = inputImage[inputIndex];
        inputIndex += 2;
        outputIndex++;
        // cout << "The pixel at " << p*OUTPUT_NUM_COL+q << " is " << outputImage[p*OUTPUT_NUM_COL+q] << endl;
    }
  }
}
```

You could do the incrementing inline with the copying assignment too, and you could also only assign inputIndex and outputIndex the first time, but it wouldn't get you as much of a performance boost as moving the calculation out of the inner loop. I assume that bulk copying functions don't have this kind of incrementing flexibility, but if they do and they use hardware acceleration that is available on all of your target platforms, then that would be a better choice.

I am also assuming that array access like this compiles down to the most optimized pointer arithmetic that you could use.

Comment: Should have thought of this! Thanks. +1

Comment: this does not take into account the actual size of each pixel and does not reduce image vertically and does not handle the 'multiple of 4 bytes' requirement for each row.

Comment: @user3629249 - The factor of 2 difference between the inputIndex and outputIndex calculation accomplishes the vertical decimation. If you mean that the total number of bytes per row needs to be a multiple of 4 bytes, then the constants for both 480 and 240 guarantee that it will be. If instead you are talking about bit depth per pixel, then it wasn't stated that this was a 32-bits-per-pixel image and would need 4 bytes per pixel. I could only assume from the question that it was an 8-bits-per-pixel image.

Comment: Assumptions, when writing software, are (or will be) a bane to any programmers' life.  Your answer does not handle the fact that each pixel (depending on the info in the file header can be 1,3,or 4 bytes in length.  The reading a `int` sized amount of bytes is not reliable.  What happens on a 64bit architecture?  What happens on a 16bit architecture? What happens when each pixel is 3 bytes? What happens when each pixel is 1 byte?